# Granola from oat groats

Tags: baking, grains, granola

I would like to make granola using a completely whole grain- the oat groat. How can I make granola from oat groats? Should I half-cook them and then put them in the oven?

Comment: Oat groats take quite a lot of cooking. 2 hours on brown rice setting (2 cycles) of my rice cooker. Even then I'd be concerned about the groats getting hard when dry. Rolled oats might be a better choice: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolled_oats

Comment: [This](http://www.includingcake.com/blog/easy-traditional-oat-groats) no-cook recipe suggests soaking overnight in hot water makes them soft enough to eat. But again as Wayfaring said, they might get hard when dry.